# Attempting to share Object between WPF windows

Tags: c#, wpf, oop

I instantiate a class in the MainWindow of my WPF application, then pass that Object to a second window on a click event. But when I attempt to run a method of the Object I passed to the second window in the Window_Loaded method I get the error:

> The name `object` does not exist in the current context.

This is my MainWindow code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    Object objectName;

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
            objectName = new Object();
            objectName.Text = "text";




    }
    private void MenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Settings settingsWindow = new Settings(objectName);
        settingsWindow.Show();
    }
}
```

and the SettingsWindow:

```
public partial class Settings : Window
{
    public Settings(Object object)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void SettingsWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // get text in object
        String name = object.Text;
    }
}
```

So I am able to pass the Object to the Window but how can I use it in the new windows Window_Loaded method?

Comment: You are passing the Object around, but you don't have a reference to it in your Settings Window, since you are not storing it locally in your constructor.

Comment: Use a `ViewModel`. Read up to MVVM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't instantiate object in Settings.

Use:

```
public partial class  Settings: Window
{
    Object _object;

    public Settings(Object object)
    {
        _object = object
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void SettingsWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // get text in object
        String name = _object.Text;
    }
```

Also some offtopic tips:

- Use MVVM
- Don't use an Object directly, but a more specific class type (make your own).
- Rename Settings to SettingsWindow, because high likely you also might have a Settings class containing data.

Comment: It might be overwhelming at start, but if you go into bigger programs (with unit testing), it really pays off.

Answer (score 2):

YOu go wrong on some diffirent things. First you can not use objects with this syntax. you can only go trough it by using reflection, or by converting it to a dictionary. SO it would be better to actually make a class for it:

```
class MyClass{
  public string Text;
}
```

now change this in your settings window:

MyClass objectName;

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        objectName = new MyClass();
        objectName.Text = "text";
}
```

and the last thing you will need to change is the other form it will look like this:

```
public partial class  Settings: Window
{
    MyClass _object;

    public Settings(Object object)
    {
        _object = object
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void SettingsWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // get text in object
        var name = _object.Text;
    }
}
```